# Two lines with different width in the header using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I want create the attached header style for my document?
Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Do you want the *header* to look like that? Or do you want *chapter titles* to look like that? A header is the running text at the top of pages. For example, it might include the name of the book, chapter or section, a page number or an author. Usually, no header is included on the first page of a chapter (in the standard classes) to accommodate the title of the chapter, which typically includes the word 'Chapter', a number and the title itself and may be formatted in various ways.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Or do you want the header on the first page of chapters to look like that? Is 'This is my Title' the title of the chapter? What is 'Chapter Name'? Or is 'This is my Title' the title of something else and 'Chapter Name' is the chapter title? Really confused :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redefine the `\headrule` that is offered by `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand\headrule{%
  \begingroup
  \vspace{1pt}
  \hrule height 2pt width\headwidth
  \vspace{1pt}
  \hrule height 0.7pt width\headwidth
  \endgroup
}
\chead{Some heading}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the intended question even though it answers the actual question. I'm not at all sure about this though.

Comment: @cfr I read the question and when it is understood, I never see the content of the picture ;-)

Comment: Well, you did answer the question asked. (Insofar as there is a well-formed question at all.) Plus, with the image, I don't really understand the question so your strategy may be advisable. I was guessing the 'This is my Title' is supposed to be the chapter title. But then what is 'Chapter Name'? (Or maybe it is meant to be the header for the first page of chapters?)

Comment: @cfr I too had some confusion and then assumed it is the header.

Comment: Thank you all, this is exactly what I wanted. Chapter Name is the title of the chapter while This is my title is just the content of that chapter. Yea, the question was confusing, but thanks for guessing it and answering it correctly.